# Is there a way to exclude all the fields from @EqualsAndHashCode other than the @Id column

Tags: lombok

From my domain/Pojo I wanted to exclude all the fields but `@EmbeddedId` or `@Id`.

One way to exclude them is to use `@Exclude` on all the fields, I wanted to know if there an another short method?

e.g.

```
@Entity(name = "TestView")
@Table(name = "Test_View")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class TestView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9181710663858694093L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRCL_SEQ_NUM")
    private Integer prclSeqNum;

    @Exclude
    @Column(name = "CMPS_TAKE_ACQ_VAL")
    private String takeAcq;

    @Exclude
    @Column(name = "REMND_ACQ_IND")
    private String remndAcqInd;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` on the class and then `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include` on the field to include.